# Additional PUT/PATCH route for Route::resource

Tags: laravel

I have a standard resource route for users:

`Route::resource('users', 'UserController');`

Yet I want to add an additional route for a submitted form that binds an existing User's roles/permissions.

#### `UserController`

```
public function updateRolesPermissions(Request $request){
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

#### `show.blade.php`

I tried both this:

`{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['users.updateRolesPermissions', $user->id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}`

and this:

`{!! Form::open(['action' => 'UserController@updateRolesPermissions']) !!}`

What would be the best way to add an additional route to a resource route **without opening a new separate route?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *best* way is to add another route.

```
Route::patch('users/{user_id}/roles_permissions', 'UserController@ updateRolesPermissions');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

This is the way it should be done, so it is the most clear to somebody coming to the project fresh or new. Trying to be too clever about it will make it hard to find and maintain at a later date.

With route model binding, this should behave the same way as your other routes.

Comment: Hey Thomas and thanks, but I specifically asked not for a seperate route since I've set a grouped middlweware so I need to stay in resource as i'm checking each route for `$pathInfo = $request->segment(1)`

Comment: Yeah I figured there would be a reason =) I think you’ll find it easier to still use the route the way it’s designed. There’s a huge amount of work that goes on behind the scenes that you’ll end up trying to replicate. Can you just not add that new route to your middleware?

Comment: I doubt it'll pass code review, as all routes arrays and then I have to create a seperate else-if. I'll try to set this up. please be in listen mode if I have any questions, if all goes well more than happy to sign this as answer, thanks Thomas.

Comment: Not sure what your routes file sounds like, but that seems odd? The routes file should be pretty simple, otherwise I’m not sure I’d trust who’s passing your code reviews :D

Comment: can you please write the Form::class method here also?
I have route as: `Route::patch('users/{id}/roles-permissions', ['as' => 'roles-permissions', 'uses' => 'UserController@updateRolesPermissions']);` and my Form as follows: `{!! Form::open(['action' => 'UserController@updateRolesPermissions', $user->id]) !!}` and error:
`Missing required parameters for [Route: roles-permissions] [URI: users/{id}/roles-permissions]`

Comment: I don’t use `Form::open` I’m afraid as it’s no longer part of Laravel, but `route('roles-permissions', ['id' => $user->id])` is probably the bit you’re looking for. Don’t forget that you can use `{user}` in your route instead of `{id}` for implicit route binding too.

Comment: Thanks @Tpojka – the supplementing routes should go _before_ the resource.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Way to go. :thumbup: